# Facet_grid using scales="free_x" displaying x values from other grids

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I'm trying to create an easier to read x-axis with days and months as one subtitle and years on the second x-axis title below. I've used facet_grid to facet by year and I've used scales="free_x" to allow the x axis to vary by year, however days and months from other years are showing up in the grid for a specific year. I'd like this graph to look more seamless and for lines to connect through each facet year. Anyone know why this is happening?

My data:

```
structure(list(name1 = 1:81, NumPos_curr = c(1, 5, 3, 6, 0, 0, 
2, 5, 6, 2, 3, 8, 5, 7, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 12, 2, 1, 
11, 14, 15, 10, 30, 15, 15, 30, 17, 12, 10, 3, 11, 5, 1, 19, 
13, 17, 23, 1, 5, 6, 2, 4, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 8, 1, 1, 0, 17, 28, 
21, 28, 39, 32, 22, 10, 9, 13, 13, 11, 5, 5, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 
0, 0), NumNeg_curr = c(5, 149, 245, 291, 8, 1, 130, 148, 194, 
203, 178, 156, 119, 208, 173, 75, 68, 128, 88, 59, 106, 122, 
90, 272, 133, 289, 350, 332, 452, 435, 401, 347, 437, 771, 399, 
536, 444, 461, 377, 465, 497, 647, 856, 823, 1203, 19, 22, 109, 
319, 461, 465, 397, 280, 625, 369, 545, 59, 1, 15, 491, 446, 
403, 529, 653, 699, 746, 594, 562, 424, 381, 602, 651, 549, 592, 
529, 169, 579, 674, 732, 755, 736), PerPos_Ind_curr = c(16.7, 
3.2, 1.2, 2, 0, 0, 1.5, 3.3, 3, 1, 1.7, 4.9, 4, 3.3, 1.7, 1.3, 
1.4, 0.8, 1.1, 0, 1.9, 0.8, 2.2, 4.2, 1.5, 0.3, 3, 4, 3.2, 2.2, 
7, 4.1, 3.3, 3.7, 4.1, 2.2, 2.2, 0.6, 2.8, 1.1, 0.2, 2.9, 1.5, 
2, 1.9, 5, 18.5, 5.2, 0.6, 0.9, 0.2, 0, 0.7, 0.5, 0.3, 1.4, 1.7, 
50, 0, 3.3, 5.9, 5, 5, 5.6, 4.4, 2.9, 1.7, 1.6, 3, 3.3, 1.8, 
0.8, 0.9, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.3, 0, 0, 0), Start.Date = structure(c(18587, 
18594, 18601, 18608, 18615, 18622, 18629, 18636, 18643, 18650, 
18657, 18664, 18671, 18678, 18685, 18692, 18699, 18706, 18713, 
18720, 18727, 18734, 18741, 18748, 18755, 18762, 18769, 18776, 
18783, 18790, 18797, 18804, 18811, 18818, 18825, 18832, 18839, 
18846, 18853, 18860, 18867, 18874, 18881, 18888, 18895, 18902, 
18909, 18916, 18923, 18930, 18937, 18944, 18951, 18958, 18965, 
18972, 18979, 18986, 18993, 19000, 19007, 19014, 19021, 19028, 
19035, 19042, 19049, 19056, 19063, 19070, 19077, 19084, 19091, 
19098, 19105, 19112, 19119, 19126, 19133, 19140, 19147), class = "Date"), 
    End.Date = structure(c(18593, 18600, 18607, 18614, 18621, 
    18628, 18635, 18642, 18649, 18656, 18663, 18670, 18677, 18684, 
    18691, 18698, 18705, 18712, 18719, 18726, 18733, 18740, 18747, 
    18754, 18761, 18768, 18775, 18782, 18789, 18796, 18803, 18810, 
    18817, 18824, 18831, 18838, 18845, 18852, 18859, 18866, 18873, 
    18880, 18887, 18894, 18901, 18908, 18915, 18922, 18929, 18936, 
    18943, 18950, 18957, 18964, 18971, 18978, 18985, 18992, 18999, 
    19006, 19013, 19020, 19027, 19034, 19041, 19048, 19055, 19062, 
    19069, 19076, 19083, 19090, 19097, 19104, 19111, 19118, 19125, 
    19132, 19139, 19146, 19153), class = "Date"), Weekly...Test.Positivity = c(12, 
    12.4, 13.2, 12, 11.3, 11.3, 13.4, 12.8, 9.6, 8.5, 6.9, 5.9, 
    5, 4.1, 3.9, 3.7, 3.6, 3.8, 4.1, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7, 4.2, 4.1, 
    3.6, 3, 2.7, 2.2, 2, 1.9, 1.9, 2.1, 2.7, 3.9, 5.2, 7.4, 9.5, 
    10.5, 11, 11.2, 11.1, 10.1, 9.6, 8.6, 7.7, 7.4, 7.1, 6.5, 
    6.1, 6.1, 6.3, 7, 7.3, 8.2, 9, 8.4, 9.3, 14.4, 25.1, 30.5, 
    30.2, 27.6, 22.1, 16, 10.6, 7.1, 5.1, 3.7, 3.1, 2.8, 2.7, 
    3, 3.5, 4.4, 5.7, 6.8, 8.4, 9.9, 10.2, 10.4, 10.8), dates = c("2020-11-21 to 2020-11-27", 
    "2020-11-28 to 2020-12-04", "2020-12-05 to 2020-12-11", "2020-12-12 to 2020-12-18", 
    "2020-12-19 to 2020-12-25", "2020-12-26 to 2021-01-01", "2021-01-02 to 2021-01-08", 
    "2021-01-09 to 2021-01-15", "2021-01-16 to 2021-01-22", "2021-01-23 to 2021-01-29", 
    "2021-01-30 to 2021-02-05", "2021-02-06 to 2021-02-12", "2021-02-13 to 2021-02-19", 
    "2021-02-20 to 2021-02-26", "2021-02-27 to 2021-03-05", "2021-03-06 to 2021-03-12", 
    "2021-03-13 to 2021-03-19", "2021-03-20 to 2021-03-26", "2021-03-27 to 2021-04-02", 
    "2021-04-03 to 2021-04-09", "2021-04-10 to 2021-04-16", "2021-04-17 to 2021-04-23", 
    "2021-04-24 to 2021-04-30", "2021-05-01 to 2021-05-07", "2021-05-08 to 2021-05-14", 
    "2021-05-15 to 2021-05-21", "2021-05-22 to 2021-05-28", "2021-05-29 to 2021-06-04", 
    "2021-06-05 to 2021-06-11", "2021-06-12 to 2021-06-18", "2021-06-19 to 2021-06-25", 
    "2021-06-26 to 2021-07-02", "2021-07-03 to 2021-07-09", "2021-07-10 to 2021-07-16", 
    "2021-07-17 to 2021-07-23", "2021-07-24 to 2021-07-30", "2021-07-31 to 2021-08-06", 
    "2021-08-07 to 2021-08-13", "2021-08-14 to 2021-08-20", "2021-08-21 to 2021-08-27", 
    "2021-08-28 to 2021-09-03", "2021-09-04 to 2021-09-10", "2021-09-11 to 2021-09-17", 
    "2021-09-18 to 2021-09-24", "2021-09-25 to 2021-10-01", "2021-10-02 to 2021-10-08", 
    "2021-10-09 to 2021-10-15", "2021-10-16 to 2021-10-22", "2021-10-23 to 2021-10-29", 
    "2021-10-30 to 2021-11-05", "2021-11-06 to 2021-11-12", "2021-11-13 to 2021-11-19", 
    "2021-11-20 to 2021-11-26", "2021-11-27 to 2021-12-03", "2021-12-04 to 2021-12-10", 
    "2021-12-11 to 2021-12-17", "2021-12-18 to 2021-12-24", "2021-12-25 to 2021-12-31", 
    "2022-01-01 to 2022-01-07", "2022-01-08 to 2022-01-14", "2022-01-15 to 2022-01-21", 
    "2022-01-22 to 2022-01-28", "2022-01-29 to 2022-02-04", "2022-02-05 to 2022-02-11", 
    "2022-02-12 to 2022-02-18", "2022-02-19 to 2022-02-25", "2022-02-26 to 2022-03-04", 
    "2022-03-05 to 2022-03-11", "2022-03-12 to 2022-03-18", "2022-03-19 to 2022-03-25", 
    "2022-03-26 to 2022-04-01", "2022-04-02 to 2022-04-08", "2022-04-09 to 2022-04-15", 
    "2022-04-16 to 2022-04-22", "2022-04-23 to 2022-04-29", "2022-04-30 to 2022-05-06", 
    "2022-05-07 to 2022-05-13", "2022-05-14 to 2022-05-20", "2022-05-21 to 2022-05-27", 
    "2022-05-28 to 2022-06-03", "2022-06-04 to 2022-06-10"), 
    sum_people = c(6, 154, 248, 297, 8, 1, 132, 153, 200, 205, 
    181, 164, 124, 215, 176, 76, 69, 129, 89, 59, 108, 123, 92, 
    284, 135, 290, 361, 346, 467, 445, 431, 362, 452, 801, 416, 
    548, 454, 464, 388, 470, 498, 666, 869, 840, 1226, 20, 27, 
    115, 321, 465, 466, 397, 282, 628, 370, 553, 60, 2, 15, 508, 
    474, 424, 557, 692, 731, 768, 604, 571, 437, 394, 613, 656, 
    554, 593, 529, 169, 580, 676, 732, 755, 736), DayMonth = c("11-21", 
    "11-28", "12-05", "12-12", "12-19", "12-26", "01-02", "01-09", 
    "01-16", "01-23", "01-30", "02-06", "02-13", "02-20", "02-27", 
    "03-06", "03-13", "03-20", "03-27", "04-03", "04-10", "04-17", 
    "04-24", "05-01", "05-08", "05-15", "05-22", "05-29", "06-05", 
    "06-12", "06-19", "06-26", "07-03", "07-10", "07-17", "07-24", 
    "07-31", "08-07", "08-14", "08-21", "08-28", "09-04", "09-11", 
    "09-18", "09-25", "10-02", "10-09", "10-16", "10-23", "10-30", 
    "11-06", "11-13", "11-20", "11-27", "12-04", "12-11", "12-18", 
    "12-25", "01-01", "01-08", "01-15", "01-22", "01-29", "02-05", 
    "02-12", "02-19", "02-26", "03-05", "03-12", "03-19", "03-26", 
    "04-02", "04-09", "04-16", "04-23", "04-30", "05-07", "05-14", 
    "05-21", "05-28", "06-04"), year = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
    2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
    2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
    2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
    2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
    2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
    2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022)), row.names = c(NA, 
-81L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My graph:

```
normalizer<-max(Graph_overall$sum_people) / max(Graph_overall$PerPos_Ind_curr)

Overall_graph<-ggplot(data=Graph_overall, aes(x=name1, y=PerPos_Ind_curr)) +
   geom_col(data=Graph_overall,
           aes(x = name1,
               y = sum_people / normalizer),
           fill="light grey") + 
  geom_line(aes(x=name1, y=PerPos_Ind_curr))+
  geom_line(aes(x=name1, y=Weekly...Test.Positivity), size=1, color="#B51963")+

  theme_bw() +
  labs(x="Month", y="% Positive") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 81, by = 1),
                     labels = Graph_overall$DayMonth)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "dark grey"))+
   scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans= ~.*normalizer,
                                         name = 'Number of Arrivals')) +
  facet_grid(~ year, space="free_x", scales="free_x", switch="x") +
    theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour="grey70"),
        panel.spacing.x=unit(0,"line"))

Overall_graph
```

Comment: Add `expand = expansion(add = 0)` or `expand = c(0,0)` to your `scale_x_continuous` to remove padding to the scale.